# Angular api call in stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to redirect user to some state I get from api call like this:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
             event.preventDefault();
             AppService
                 .currentState()
                 .success(function(data) {
                        $state.transitionTo(data.pageName, null, {notify:false});
                 });
         });
```

This causes the url to change correctly but the page is not rendered. Any ideas why?

I even tried without api call like

```
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $state.go('app.home', null, {location: true, notify:false});
  });
```

Comment: If the URL changes but the page doesn't get rendered I'm guessing you have some problems with the template definition. Could you show us the **app.home** state definition and also your views structure?

Comment: Bro It's going on cyclic loop every time you call $state.go it's coming to $stateChangeStart and it's preventing it to do it's stuff

Comment: @SiddharthPandey nope! Notice the `notify:false` which tell ui-router not to broadcast the $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events. Source: [$state.go docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go()` instead of using `$state.transitionTo()`

```
$state.go(data.pageName, null, {notify:false});
```

Comment: no, nothing :-/ state.go is called with correct state name but nothing happens

Answer (score -2):

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {

$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
  $rootScope.authenticated = false;

  Data.get('auth/check_session').then(function (results) {

    if (results.uid) 
    {
      $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      $rootScope.uid = results.uid;

      var nextUrl = $location.path();

      if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/signin' || nextUrl == '/forgot-password') {
        $location.path("/dashboard");
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
      //var nextUrl = next.originalPath;
      var nextUrl = $location.path();//next.$location.originalPath;

      if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == 'app/signin') {
      } 
      else 
      {
        $location.path("/signin");
      }
    }
  });
});

});
```